# iOS ooVoo. How can i notice when someone from conference hangs up?

Tags: ios, freeze, videochat, oovoo

> i use oovoo sdk.

how can i notice when someone from conference hangs up?

```
- (void)initSDKInitializer {

self.sdk = [ooVooClient sharedInstance];
self.sdk.AVChat.delegate = self;
self.sdk.AVChat.VideoController.delegate = self;
self.defaultCameraId = [self.sdk.AVChat.VideoController getConfig:ooVooVideoControllerConfigKeyCaptureDeviceId];
self.currentRes = self.defaultRes = [self.sdk.AVChat.VideoController getConfig:ooVooVideoControllerConfigKeyResolution];


[self.sdk.AVChat.VideoController setConfig:self.currentRes forKey:ooVooVideoControllerConfigKeyResolution];

self.ownVideoPanelView.fitVideoMode = YES;

[self.sdk.AVChat.VideoController bindVideoRender:self.userId render:self.ownVideoPanelView];

[self.sdk.AVChat.VideoController openCamera];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.toolBarView];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

So the delegate method gets called when someone leave the conference. 
I believe there's 4 - 5 required delegate method you have to conform to when you set the AVChat's delegate.

```
- (void)didParticipantLeave:(id<ooVooParticipant>)participant;
```

Is one of them ad this is notified when someone drops out of the video conference.